# How to link against third-party libraries (.lib) in Team Services build of GitHub repo?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, github, azure-devops

Adding the libs in the source control and adding the correct paths to the Visual Studio solution does absolutely nothing. My local project compiles fine, but the online CI compilation fails every time.

```
LINK(0,0): Error LNK1104: cannot open file 'xxx.lib'
```

I've tried any possible combination of relative paths and settings that work in VS2015 at this point. The documentation is really scarce and all I was able to find was some ambiguous advice around TFS project files (which I don't have, because the repo is a remote GitHub repo) and workspaces (which I don't know how to set up). I'm also aware of this "NuGet" package thing, but I'd rather not have to construct an entire dedicated package for a couple of library files that I already have in the directories.

I can't believe there really just isn't a simple setting to include third-party SDKs though. Even including the libs in the source control is bad practice, so I might have missed something pretty big here. Any advice?

Comment: Where did you place the lib file? I place the lib file in project folder and add it in source control. The build can be finished successfully.

Comment: The lib file is not in the root directory, it's in its own set of folders inside the project folder together with other libraries and other versions of the files (MD, MT, etc.)

Comment: Did you keep the same relative path after add it into version control? If yes, you should does not need to update the solution file.

Comment: Yes, I've added the relative path to the VC++ directories inside VS2015 and the same folder structure is kept inside the repo. Do I need to set it up  anywhere else? Edit: sorry, I meant "inside the solution folder" earlier, not the (sub)project folder, if it makes any difference.

Comment: I added my folder structure which can be built successfully in answer so that you can check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is my folder structure in local and VSTS:

In my local machine, lib file is placed in "test" folder under "MyCon" project folder:
[image]

The folder structure is almost the same after added into source control:
[image]

Path in Linker:
[image]

Settings if the lib file is in solution folder:
[image]

Comment: Here's my problem: I don't have any repo *on* VSTS, it's all on GitHub. I don't want to have to manage two source controls at the same time, the Visual Studio solution compiles fine, and I'd like to use VSTS only as a CI integration on GitHub.

Comment: @Banderi GitHub reposiotry is the same. You just need to make sure the folder structure is consistent.

Comment: In that case, I'll try to move the library folders from the solution root to the project root and see if it works.

Comment: @Banderi I added the screenshot for solution folder.

Comment: I double-checked the source control structure, and it seems the lib files were being ignored by git, thought the folders were actually there, empty. Now it's all working successfully.

Comment: @Banderi Glad to hear that. :)